# get the instance id of an application which is running on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

We have a springboot application (File Reading/Writing) which is deployed on `Pivotal Cloud Foundry`. Currently, only one instance is running, but now we are forced to increase the instance count to 2(Due to company policy/standard etc). If we scale up to 2, our application won't work 100% as expected, it may process same file separately , and this can cause issues.

So, my question is ,

1. is there any way, we can set the `cron` scheduler separately for each instance ? or
2. inside the spring boot application, is there any way to pass the instance number or id or any identification, saying this is instance 1 or 2 ?, so that i can restrict the execution for a certain instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility that I see commonly is to look at `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX`. [It is a zero-based index](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-INDEX) indicating which instance is running.

What I see typically done is that the app looks to see if it is index zero, then enables some functionality. If its index is greater than zero, that same functionality is turned off. That way the functionality, like a scheduler, is only running on the first instance.

You do have to keep in mind that by doing this, your scheduler is only running on one instance though and if that instance goes down the scheduler could possibly miss events it should have triggered. That may or may not matter depending on your application requirements and how the scheduler you're using behaves when it starts back up after a crash (maybe it'll catch up?).

The other possibility is to look at a more distributed scheduler, one that can cope with multiple workers. Not an endorsement, but [Jobrunr](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/) is one example in the Java space. I'm sure others exist in both Java and other languages. The hallmark of these tools is that they can coordinate work across multiple processes/containers/VMs so that you don't have jobs being run multiple times.

Comment: `@Value("${CF_INSTANCE_INDEX}")
private int intanceIndex;` -

Comment: Yes, if you are using Java and Spring Boot, that's an option. In that situation, you could also use `java-cfenv` which provides this information through convenient classes. Spring Boot is very flexible, so there are a few ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Value("${CF_INSTANCE_INDEX}")                                                                                                  
 private int intanceIndex;
```

just add the above lines and we can get the Index of instance starting from `0` inside the application.

Thanks @Daniel Mikusa