# PCF - Spring Boot - Instance Index

Tags: java, spring-boot, pcf

We have a requirement to identify the instance index number of a Spring Boot application deployed in PCF. This is to create a dynamic subscription to a Pub/Sub topic based on the CF Instance Index. How do we find the index number of the Spring Boot application instance running in PCF?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74457574/get-the-instance-id-of-an-application-which-is-running-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry

Comment: check the above SO link for the answer. `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` must be you're looking for

Comment: Thank you! We were able to read the instance index using the above property.